# SBT - task to transitively gather subprojects information

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to implement a simple task (and learn SBT - again - at the same time). After spending about 8 hours trying to figure the solution, hit many dead-end ways, read a lot of SBT docs and SO entries and having built up a massive heap of anger and frustration, I'm posting the question here.

I need to implement a task, `transitiveBaseDirectories`, that will (in sbt console) allow me to query projects for it's dependening projects tasks in a multi-project build (an example structure is at the end of this post) like this:

`projectA/transitiveBaseDirectories`

(made up desired output)

`Seq(File("./projectA"), File("./projectAA"), File("./projectAAA"), File("./projectAB")))`

for this example project

```scala
lazy val transitiveBaseDirectories = taskKey[Seq[File]](
    "Returns a list of baseDirectory-ies of all projects a given project transitively depends on."
)

def transitiveBaseDirectoriesImpl = ???

lazy val root = project.dependsOn(projectA, projectB)

lazy val projectA = project.dependsOn(projectAA, projectAB)

lazy val projectAA = project.dependsOn(projectAAA)

lazy val projectAAA = project

lazy val projectAB = project.dependsOn(projectAB)

lazy val projectB = project
```

Then it will be necessary to somehow make `transitiveBaseDirectories` available for all projects - I also don't know how to do that.

I'm deliberately not showing here all my failed attempts (various takes on `Product.extract(state.value)`, `baseDirectory.all(ScopeFilter(inDependencies(...)))` etc). On my SBT explorations I've had the "almost-there" feeling on several occasions, followed by waves of confusion and realization that I just don't get the SBT big picture necessary to complete the task, and more frustration. I've given up, again, this is my maybe third occasion to implement a non-trivial task in SBT, and it has never ended well (in the better cases, I've succeeded, but didn't really understand what I did).

I would really appreciate a minimal, but complete solution here, because I've been halfway through too many times, if I'm not asking too much.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the transitive dependencies for all the projects.

So I'll first make a task to get all the direct project dependencies.

```
val directProjectDeps = taskKey[Map[String,Seq[ProjectRef]]]("project dependencies!")

directProjectDeps := {
  val extracted = Project extract state.value
  extracted.structure.allProjects.map { p =>
    val deps = p.dependencies.map(_.project)
    (p.id, deps)
  }.toMap
}
```

Then need to do a bit of graph traversal to get all the transitive dependencies. Here's a simple implementation in a separate task.

```
val transitiveProjectDeps = taskKey[Map[String,Seq[ProjectRef]]]("transitive project dependencies!")

transitiveProjectDeps := {
  val deps = directProjectDeps.value

  def transitives(id: String): Seq[ProjectRef] = {
    val direct = deps(id)
    direct ++ direct.flatMap(d => transitives(d.project))
  }

  deps.map{ case(id,_) => (id,transitives(id)) }
}
```

To avoid dealing with dynamic references to tasks, use extracted to access the `baseDirectory` setting of all the ProjectRefs

```
val transitiveProjectDirs = taskKey[Map[String,Seq[File]]]("transitive project dependencies!")
transitiveProjectDirs := {
  val extracted = Project extract state.value
  transitiveProjectDeps.value.mapValues { v =>
    v.map(ref => extracted.get(baseDirectory in ref))
  }
}
```

To get the dirs only for the current project.

```
val myTransitiveProjectDirs = taskKey[Seq[File]]("just my dirs")
myTransitiveProjectDirs :=
  transitiveProjectDirs.value.apply(thisProjectRef.value.project)
```

To make all of the tasks available within any subproject, it's probably easiest to put them into a plugin.

Comment: Your solution does indeed work, I've marked it as an answer, thank you so much. The `extracted.get(baseDirectory in ref)` was the missing piece in my attempts. However, your solution only makes the the task available for the root project. 1) How do I add it to another single project? 2) You write that to make it available for all project, it's probably easiest to put them into a plugin. How do I do it as a part of the project, without the need to to publish the plugin separately? Thank you, Tomáš

Comment: You can define an plugin in the `project` directory of your build and it will simply be part of your build. An AutoPlugin can add itself to all your subprojects automatically. Alternatively, for your use case you can define the tasks above in a Seq and add it to all your subprojects manually with `.settings(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Justin Kaeser. Just for completeness, the whole solution, which also adds the tasks to all projects, is to

create a file `project/TransitiveDirsPlugin.scala` with the following contents:

```scala
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object TransitiveDirsPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger: PluginTrigger = allRequirements

  private[this] val directProjectDeps =
    taskKey[Map[String, Seq[ProjectRef]]]("project dependencies!")

  private[this] val transitiveProjectDeps =
    taskKey[Map[String, Seq[ProjectRef]]]("transitive project dependencies!")

  private[this] val transitiveProjectDirs =
    taskKey[Map[String, Seq[File]]]("transitive project dependencies!")

  private[this] val myTransitiveProjectDirs: TaskKey[Seq[File]] =
    taskKey[Seq[File]]("just my dirs")

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    directProjectDeps := {
      val extracted = Project extract state.value
      extracted.structure.allProjects.map { p ⇒
        val deps = p.dependencies.map(_.project)
        (p.id, deps)
      }.toMap
    },

    transitiveProjectDeps := {
      val deps = directProjectDeps.value

      def transitives(id: String): Seq[ProjectRef] = {
        val direct = deps(id)
        direct ++ direct.flatMap(d => transitives(d.project))
      }

      deps.map { case (id, _) => (id, transitives(id)) }
    },

    transitiveProjectDirs := {
      val extracted = Project extract state.value
      transitiveProjectDeps.value.mapValues { v =>
        v.map(ref => extracted.get(baseDirectory in ref))
      }
    },

    myTransitiveProjectDirs :=
      transitiveProjectDirs.value.apply(thisProjectRef.value.project)
  )
}
```

Now I can use `show projectA/myTransitiveProjectDirs` et al. Thank you, Justin.